# Select first rows where condition

Tags: sql

I want to select all distinct rows where a value is at its minimum.
Here's an example:

| Item | Quantity | Line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Article 1 | 100 | 1 |
| Article 1 | 240 | 2 |
| Article 2 | 150 | 3 |
| Article 2 | 140 | 4 |
| Article 2 | 200 | 5 |
| Article 3 | 45 | 6 |
| Article 3 | 60 | 7 |

I want the result to be :

| Item | Quantity | Line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Article 1 | 100 | 1 |
| Article 2 | 150 | 3 |
| Article 3 | 45 | 6 |

So basically i need the Quantity of every Item where Line as at its lowest value.
How can I do it with SQL?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The solution might be product specific.)

Comment: Hello, it's the query tool of Sap Business 1 ERP, I honestly don't know which is the correct answer to this